# Permanently have Caps Lock as Ctrl

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I set my `Caps Lock as Ctrl` and `Caps Lock is also a Ctrl` in gnome-tweaks. Was working perfectly until like a week ago when it started to randomly switch back to Caps. However, the settings in gnome-tweaks still remain as what I set them. I tried to run `* * * * * /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"` as a cronjob every 1 minute but it doesn't work. However, running that command manually DOES fix it.

How to I permanently make this setting? I am on `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` and have been on it for some time.

Comment: Sounds like [bug #1899206](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1899206).